# upgrading system ram to 16 GB facing error : A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, dll, jvm, ram

After upgrading my system RAM from 8GB to 16GB,JVM started crashing each time
rest other application working fine and all those application which using JVM going crashed.

I have the following below mention error while running any program and can't figure out what the solution would be. I also looked at all the topics with a similar error here, but could not resolve my issue.

with 8GB RAM JVM worked fine and my system supports 16GB but still i am not able to use java. 
i am using 64bit oracle jdk.

Here the error

```
Crash Log.
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000707c1af8, pid=7680, tid=9184
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0x421af8]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x0000000014ca5800):  JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9184, stack(0x00000000164f0000,0x00000000165f0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000060

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000040, RBX=0x0000000000000001, RCX=0x0000000000000004, RDX=0x000000000000010c
    RSP=0x00000000165eee90, RBP=0x00000000165eef90, RSI=0x000000000000000e, RDI=0x0000000000000001
    R8 =0x0000000000001000, R9 =0x0000000000000003, R10=0x0000000000001003, R11=0x0000000000000001
    R12=0x0000000000000019, R13=0x00000000180f8590, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x0000000000000000
    RIP=0x00000000707c1af8, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000165eee90)
    0x00000000165eee90:   000000002aae3dd0 00000000165eef90
    0x00000000165eeea0:   000000000000000e 0000000000000001
    0x00000000165eeeb0:   0000000016e2bc00 0000000000000000
    0x00000000165eeec0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000165eeed0:   0000000000000000 000000001998c400
    0x00000000165eeee0:   0000000000000240 0000000000000000
    0x00000000165eeef0:   000000001c87d800 0000000000000000
    0x00000000165eef00:   000000bf00000000 000000001998c3b0
    0x00000000165eef10:   0000000000000240 0000000017233d40
    0x00000000165eef20:   0000000000000011 000000000000000e
    0x00000000165eef30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000165eef40:   0000000000000000 00000000707cf300
    0x00000000165eef50:   0000000017237710 000000000000023f
    0x00000000165eef60:   0000000000000001 0000000000000240
    0x00000000165eef70:   00000000180f8590 000000002aae36f0
    0x00000000165eef80:   0000000000000019 000000000000003c 

    Instructions: (pc=0x00000000707c1af8)
    0x00000000707c1ad8:   ff 48 85 c0 0f 8e 6a 01 00 00 4c 8b f0 66 66 66
    0x00000000707c1ae8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 4a 8b 84 fd 00 03 00 00
    0x00000000707c1af8:   4c 8b 68 20 4d 85 ed 0f 84 29 01 00 00 66 66 66
    0x00000000707c1b08:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 45 8b 65 18 33 ff 45 85 


    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000000040 is an unknown value
    RBX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
    RCX=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
    RDX=0x000000000000010c is an unknown value
    RSP=0x00000000165eee90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000014ca5800
    RBP=0x00000000165eef90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000014ca5800
    RSI=0x000000000000000e is an unknown value
    RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
    R8 =0x0000000000001000 is an unknown value
    R9 =0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
    R10=0x0000000000001003 is an unknown value
    R11=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
    R12=0x0000000000000019 is an unknown value
    R13=0x00000000180f8590 is an unknown value
    R14=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
    R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x00000000164f0000,0x00000000165f0000],  sp=0x00000000165eee90,  free space=1019k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0x421af8]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x427306]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x405e70]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x406240]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x406372]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x406541]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x40674f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xa4352]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xa4c8f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x241984]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x29853a]
    C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21d9f]
    C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21e3b]
    C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x18102]
    C  [ntdll.dll+0x5c5b4]


    Current CompileTask:
    C1: 581961 20462 %     3       sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder::encodeArrayLoop @ 88 (236 bytes)


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x0000000016ebe000 JavaThread "Thread-60" daemon [_thread_new, id=9156, stack(0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)]
      0x0000000016ebf800 JavaThread "Worker-16" [_thread_blocked, id=7640, stack(0x000000002d7d0000,0x000000002d8d0000)]
      0x0000000016ebf000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6628, stack(0x000000002f700000,0x000000002f800000)]
      0x000000001cebc000 JavaThread "Worker-14" [_thread_in_vm, id=5116, stack(0x000000002e500000,0x000000002e600000)]
      0x000000001cebb800 JavaThread "Worker-13" [_thread_in_vm, id=7460, stack(0x000000002e000000,0x000000002e100000)]
      0x000000001ceb7800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4432, stack(0x000000002df00000,0x000000002e000000)]
      0x0000000026a28800 JavaThread "Support Information Request Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1868, stack(0x0000000029130000,0x0000000029230000)]
      0x0000000026a27800 JavaThread "Worker-11" [_thread_in_vm, id=1384, stack(0x0000000029030000,0x0000000029130000)]
      0x0000000026a24000 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6696, stack(0x0000000028f30000,0x0000000029030000)]
      0x0000000026a27000 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8112, stack(0x0000000028e30000,0x0000000028f30000)]
      0x000000001ceba800 JavaThread "Thread-8" [_thread_in_native, id=5876, stack(0x0000000028390000,0x0000000028490000)]
      0x000000001ceb8800 JavaThread "com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6800, stack(0x0000000027b40000,0x0000000027c40000)]
      0x000000001ceb1000 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=7416, stack(0x0000000026300000,0x0000000026400000)]
      0x000000001ceb0000 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3300, stack(0x0000000023df0000,0x0000000023ef0000)]
      0x000000001ceb3000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7868, stack(0x0000000022880000,0x0000000022980000)]
      0x0000000017a7c800 JavaThread "EventAdmin Async Event Dispatcher Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8160, stack(0x0000000020090000,0x0000000020190000)]
      0x0000000017a80000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=6744, stack(0x000000001f6e0000,0x000000001f7e0000)]
      0x000000001d81e800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9032, stack(0x000000001e130000,0x000000001e230000)]
      0x00000000177d3000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6376, stack(0x000000001ad60000,0x000000001ae60000)]
      0x0000000019486800 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2100, stack(0x000000001a270000,0x000000001a370000)]
      0x0000000017afb800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=7544, stack(0x0000000018ba0000,0x0000000018ca0000)]
      0x0000000017fb3800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4188, stack(0x00000000189c0000,0x0000000018ac0000)]
      0x0000000017b02800 JavaThread "Start Level: Equinox Container: 2014229c-3fe9-0017-120c-d2a2cee8f221" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7292, stack(0x00000000185c0000,0x00000000186c0000)]
      0x0000000017547000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 2014229c-3fe9-0017-120c-d2a2cee8f221" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8608, stack(0x00000000184c0000,0x00000000185c0000)]
      0x0000000017cba800 JavaThread "Active Thread: Equinox Container: 2014229c-3fe9-0017-120c-d2a2cee8f221" [_thread_blocked, id=9080, stack(0x00000000183c0000,0x00000000184c0000)]
      0x0000000016613800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7668, stack(0x00000000169f0000,0x0000000016af0000)]
    =>0x0000000014ca5800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9184, stack(0x00000000164f0000,0x00000000165f0000)]
      0x0000000014ca2000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5452, stack(0x00000000163f0000,0x00000000164f0000)]
      0x0000000014c9c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6596, stack(0x00000000162f0000,0x00000000163f0000)]
      0x0000000014c9a800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5708, stack(0x00000000161f0000,0x00000000162f0000)]
      0x0000000014c99800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5608, stack(0x00000000160f0000,0x00000000161f0000)]
      0x00000000025a7000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8228, stack(0x0000000015ef0000,0x0000000015ff0000)]
      0x000000000259e800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7048, stack(0x0000000015df0000,0x0000000015ef0000)]
      0x00000000025ce800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7872, stack(0x0000000000050000,0x0000000000150000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x0000000014c67000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000015cf0000,0x0000000015df0000] [id=7136]
      0x000000001661c800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000016af0000,0x0000000016bf0000] [id=5084]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
    [0x00000000025cb850] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000026a27800

    Heap:
     PSYoungGen      total 167936K, used 31138K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fdf80000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 20% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ec968b68,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 16896K, 0% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f4f00000)
      to   space 82432K, 0% used [0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000fdf80000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 174521K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 26% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000caa6e510,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 105843K, capacity 117366K, committed 117632K, reserved 1150976K
      class space    used 12324K, capacity 15621K, committed 15744K, reserved 1048576K

    Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011990000,0x0000000011ba0000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011390000

    Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000070ba4040
     Begin Bits: [0x0000000012100000, 0x0000000013100000)
     End Bits:   [0x0000000013100000, 0x0000000014100000)

    Polling page: 0x0000000000910000

    CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=52368Kb max_used=53123Kb free=193391Kb
     bounds [0x00000000025d0000, 0x0000000005ac0000, 0x00000000115d0000]
     total_blobs=14997 nmethods=14043 adapters=857
     compilation: enabled

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 581.733 Thread 0x0000000014c9c000 20454       4       java.lang.Class::getMethod0 (40 bytes)
    Event: 581.733 Thread 0x0000000014ca2000 20455       4       java.lang.Class::privateGetMethodRecursive (130 bytes)
    Event: 581.734 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 nmethod 20453 0x00000000043b2bd0 code [0x00000000043b2dc0, 0x00000000043b3638]
    Event: 581.739 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 20456       1       org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer::getDocument (5 bytes)
    Event: 581.740 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 nmethod 20456 0x000000000455c090 code [0x000000000455c1e0, 0x000000000455c2f0]
    Event: 581.743 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 20457 % !   3       sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder::encodeBufferLoop @ 5 (183 bytes)
    Event: 581.746 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 nmethod 20457% 0x00000000049f4c90 code [0x00000000049f4f40, 0x00000000049f6308]
    Event: 581.760 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 20459   !   3       org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager::classForName (120 bytes)
    Event: 581.762 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 nmethod 20459 0x0000000004888290 code [0x0000000004888540, 0x00000000048899e8]
    Event: 581.763 Thread 0x0000000014ca5800 20462 %     3       sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder::encodeArrayLoop @ 88 (236 bytes)

    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 464.353 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=47 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 235008K, used 139352K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff500000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 127488K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f2780000,0x00000000f2780000)
      from space 107520K, 11% used [0x00000000f2780000,0x00000000f33160f0,0x00000000f9080000)
      to   space 102400K, 0% used [0x00000000f9100000,0x00000000f9100000,0x00000000ff500000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 213460K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 32% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd075368,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103156K, capacity 114606K, committed 114944K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12036K, capacity 15301K, committed 15360K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 464.363 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=47 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 236544K, used 11972K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff180000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 137728K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3180000)
      from space 98816K, 12% used [0x00000000f9100000,0x00000000f9cb1118,0x00000000ff180000)
      to   space 97792K, 0% used [0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f9100000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 213460K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 32% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd075368,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103156K, capacity 114606K, committed 114944K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12036K, capacity 15301K, committed 15360K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 464.447 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=48 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 236544K, used 149700K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff180000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 137728K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3180000)
      from space 98816K, 12% used [0x00000000f9100000,0x00000000f9cb1118,0x00000000ff180000)
      to   space 97792K, 0% used [0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f9100000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 213460K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 32% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd075368,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103160K, capacity 114606K, committed 114944K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12036K, capacity 15301K, committed 15360K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 464.458 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=48 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 235520K, used 13741K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff500000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 137728K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3180000)
      from space 97792K, 14% used [0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3eeb4b8,0x00000000f9100000)
      to   space 92672K, 0% used [0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000ff500000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 213460K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 32% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd075368,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103160K, capacity 114606K, committed 114944K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12036K, capacity 15301K, committed 15360K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 467.556 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=49 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 235520K, used 151469K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff500000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 137728K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3180000)
      from space 97792K, 14% used [0x00000000f3180000,0x00000000f3eeb4b8,0x00000000f9100000)
      to   space 92672K, 0% used [0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000ff500000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 213460K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 32% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd075368,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103982K, capacity 115438K, committed 115840K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12102K, capacity 15365K, committed 15488K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 467.579 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=49 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 231936K, used 14366K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fe980000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 80896K, 17% used [0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000fa887be8,0x00000000fe980000)
      to   space 87552K, 0% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f9400000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 220477K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 34% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd74f468,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 103982K, capacity 115438K, committed 115840K, reserved 1148928K
      class space    used 12102K, capacity 15365K, committed 15488K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 508.811 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=50 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 231936K, used 74970K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fe980000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 40% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ee62ed10,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 80896K, 17% used [0x00000000f9a80000,0x00000000fa887be8,0x00000000fe980000)
      to   space 87552K, 0% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f9400000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 220477K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 34% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd74f468,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 105491K, capacity 116918K, committed 117248K, reserved 1150976K
      class space    used 12283K, capacity 15557K, committed 15616K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 508.833 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=50 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 167936K, used 16430K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fdf80000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 16896K, 97% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f4e8b948,0x00000000f4f00000)
      to   space 82432K, 0% used [0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000fdf80000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 220485K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 34% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd751468,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 105491K, capacity 116918K, committed 117248K, reserved 1150976K
      class space    used 12283K, capacity 15557K, committed 15616K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 508.833 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=51 (full 6):
     PSYoungGen      total 167936K, used 16430K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fdf80000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 16896K, 97% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f4e8b948,0x00000000f4f00000)
      to   space 82432K, 0% used [0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000fdf80000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 220485K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 34% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd751468,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 105491K, capacity 116918K, committed 117248K, reserved 1150976K
      class space    used 12283K, capacity 15557K, committed 15616K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 509.295 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=51 (full 6):
     PSYoungGen      total 167936K, used 0K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fdf80000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 151040K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f3e80000)
      from space 16896K, 0% used [0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f3e80000,0x00000000f4f00000)
      to   space 82432K, 0% used [0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000f8f00000,0x00000000fdf80000)
     ParOldGen       total 648192K, used 174521K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e7900000, 0x00000000eab00000)
      object space 648192K, 26% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000caa6e510,0x00000000e7900000)
     Metaspace       used 105491K, capacity 116918K, committed 117248K, reserved 1150976K
      class space    used 12283K, capacity 15557K, committed 15616K, reserved 1048576K
    }

    Deoptimization events (10 events):
    Event: 483.078 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038719b8 method=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.sac.CSSChildSelectorImpl.match(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/String;)Z @ 45
    Event: 483.078 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038719b8 method=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.sac.CSSChildSelectorImpl.match(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/String;)Z @ 45
    Event: 560.711 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003f9d0a4 method=org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.checkHandle(J)Z @ 6
    Event: 565.679 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=predicate action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004a28310 method=org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setStyle(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/TextStyle;II)V @ 199
    Event: 574.858 Thread 0x0000000016ebf000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000510d154 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.WeakHashSet.cleanupGarbageCollectedValues()V @ 143
    Event: 574.877 Thread 0x0000000016ebf000 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000005a5e554 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Annotation.getSourceRange()Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ISourceRange; @ 13
    Event: 576.535 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003fc2530 method=org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.drawRunBackground(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/TextLayout$StyleItem;JLorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/RECT;IIJZ)V @ 211
    Event: 579.585 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=null_assert action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000005103c64 method=org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractLineTracker.hasActiveRewriteSession()Z @ 4
    Event: 579.586 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003a55334 method=org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.computeIndexInCategory(Ljava/lang/String;I)I @ 6
    Event: 579.586 Thread 0x00000000025ce800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003a55334 method=org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.computeIndexInCategory(Ljava/lang/String;I)I @ 6

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 495.845 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000edf13eb0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 505.846 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000edf14bd0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 515.846 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab94ac0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 525.846 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab957e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 535.847 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab96500) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 545.848 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab97220) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 555.848 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab97f40) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 565.848 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab98c90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 574.877 Thread 0x0000000016ebf000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000005a5b394 to 0x0000000005a5e4f9
    Event: 575.849 Thread 0x000000001ceba800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Receive timed out> (0x00000000eab999b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash report shows that

- the problem has happened in C1 compiler while compiling a method that does ByteBuffer access in a loop;
- you use JDK 8u45.

This makes me believe that you've hit the JVM bug [JDK-8087134](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087134).

The workaround is to disable C1 compiler with `-XX:-TieredCompilation` JVM option.
However, the better idea is to update JDK to a newer version, e.g. JDK 8u152, where this bug is already fixed.